# How to setup JNDI name for JBOSS

Tags: eclipse, jndi, jboss7.x

I have used EJB and have started it on JBOSS Server. I want to test this app so I will use a client to access this. But, I don't know how to set JNDI name for this server.

Please help me.

Comment: It totally depends on the setup for your server. I highly recommend you look into securing the JBoss instance and then doing an authenticated look-up before you get too far. There are a lot of things that affect the look-up and security is a major concern you should address sooner than later. If it won't be a concern then you don't need an enterprise server running EJBs for you. Here's a thread to get you started on the JNDI lookups. You don't need any of this for a web application:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/176538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless until  different hostname or ipaddress is specified using -b option while starting server. EJB or JBoss JNDI objects can be accessed over localhost on same machine.

Please refer following links which might help you

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessEJBsRemotely

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NamingContextFactory